# Get query string from URL that may be relative

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

As part of a custom log in page, I'm trying to get the querystring part of a URL string that may represent an absolute or a relative URL. If it's an absolute URL, I can use use the Uri.Query property, but this is not supported for relative URLs.

Is it as simple as getting the substring starting at the first instance of a '?' or is it possible for a URL to contain a question mark before the query string? Or can any other text come after the query string?

```
returnUrl.Substring(returnUrl.IndexOf('?'))
```

Where returnUrl may be absolute: `"http://www.example.com/anydir/any-page1?param=1"` or relative: `"/anydir/any-page?param=1"`

Answer (score 0):

Only the first question mark in the URL has significance to indicate the start of the query string. Any after it are treated as a literal question mark.

See [RFC 3986 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) and [3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3)

It does note however:

> The characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") are allowed to
> represent data within the fragment identifier.  Beware that some
> older, erroneous implementations may not handle this data correctly
> when it is used as the base URI for relative references

Comment: So it sounds like it should be the substring from ? to #. So is parsing the string this way the best way or is there anything built in to to help get the query string from a relative URL? I'm open to converting the relative url to an absolute, but currently I don't know if i'm dealing with a relative url or absolute url to begin with.